# In codeigniter character_limiter() not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In codeigniter `character_limiter()` function is not working

```
$this->load->helper('text');
$str="hello";
$split=character_limiter($str,3); 
echo $split;
```

**I have to use Only codeigniter. Not to use with core PHP string function**.

Answer (score 1):

From CI's docs:
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/text_helper.html#ellipsize

`If you need to truncate to an exact number of characters please see the ellipsize() function below.`

Answer (score 0):

`character_limiter()` maintains the integrity of words so the character count may be slightly more or less then what you specify, [as specified in the documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/text_helper.html#character_limiter).

If you do not want to maintain this integrity, you can use the [native substr() function](http://php.net/substr) instead :

```
$split = substr($str, 0, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is *no error* i can detect. (code is perfect)

Try this

1 . in `config.php`

```
`$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'text');`
```

**Or Else**

2. top of your controller

   ```
   class Your_Controller_name extends CI_Controller
   {
       public function  __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();
          $this->load->helper('text');           
       }
   ```